# are files in the .git directory untracked?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-bash

Are files in the .git directory untracked?  The folder displays in a semi-transparent state in Windows Explorer. I added 2 directory paths to .gitignore but "git status" does not show gitignore as a modified file. However, "git status" does display these directories as deleted (red font) and "untracked". If I wanted to push my gitignore exclude logic would I need to explicitly push these red directory references as opposed to pushing the updated gitignore file?

Comment: I don't think files in the .git directory are tracked

Comment: You ask about files in the .git directory (they are not tracked), but then talk about .gitignore which is not in the .git directory. What's the connection? Did you put .gitignore inside .git? (Yes, .gitignore can be added, committed, and pushed like any other file, and it should be).

Comment: to clarify, your `.gitignore` file should not be inside the `.git` folder. track it in your project root like everything else. nothing is tracked inside the `.git` folder.

Comment: ah great thanks for that info.  I only have basic skills. the .git folder seemed to be a central location for git configuration files so I figured that the .gitignore file would go in there as well.  your feedback clears this up for me.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, files in .git directory are untracked. I guess semi-transparent means hidden in Windows. To keep ignoring some folders you need to put your `.gitignore` file in a root of your repository (not in .git folder, just in the root) and than commit it. From the moment you staged .gitignore file it applies to your repository.